# Whats happening here?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

```
z=[0 for i in range(3)]
print(z) # [0,0,0]
x=[z for i in range(3)]
print(x) #[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
x[1][1]=7
print(x) #[[0,7,0],[0,7,0],[0,7,0]]
```

Can someone explain what's happening here?

Comment: imagine `x` as `[z, z, z]`. What happens when you alter `z`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=[z for i in range(3)]
```

In this line, it is the reference of z that is repeated as each element in the list `x`

So, when you modify one sub-list (or element of `x`), all the other elements get modified as all are just references.